# Create Table - Time Statement

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, ddl, create-table

I am having trouble trying to create a table using MS Access.

I know for sure my problem lies in the "datetime" field but I can not figure what I am missing or doing wrong.

When I click "run" I get the

> "Syntax Error in Field Definition"

```
Create Table Appointments
(DocID             char(4)             not null       primary key,
 PatID             char(8)             not null,      
 Day               varchar(8)          not null,      
 Time              datetime            not null,
 Procedure         varchar(50)         null);
```

Comment: Avoid using reserved words as field names.  Day, Time, and procedure all look suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time and procedure are reserved words, and therefore should be escaped:

```
Create Table Appointments
(DocID             char(4)             not null       primary key,
 PatID             char(8)             not null,      
 [Day]             varchar(8)          not null,      
 [Time]            datetime            not null,
 [Procedure]       varchar(50)         null);
```

Or better yet, find names that aren't reserved words:

```
Create Table Appointments
(DocID             char(4)             not null       primary key,
 PatID             char(8)             not null,      
 AppointmentDay    varchar(8)          not null,      
 AppointmentTime   datetime            not null,
 MedicalProcedure  varchar(50)         null);
```

Comment: @HansUp thanks for the correction - added escaping/renaming for that field too.

Answer (score 2):

Here `Procedure` and `Time` are reserved words and so need to be escaped using `[]` like below. See [Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335) for more information

```
Create Table Appointments
(DocID             char(4)             not null       primary key,
 PatID             char(8)             not null,      
 [Day]               varchar(8)          not null,      
 [Time]              datetime            not null,
 [Procedure]         varchar(50)         null);
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Time` & `Procedure` are reserved keyword, so wrap Time & Procedure column in brackets [] or choose alternate names, if possible. See [List of Keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335)

```
[Time] and [Procedure]
```